# Fetch API calls fail after implementing catch-all express routing solution: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I am working on a React project, and after running into the problem described here: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually?noredirect=1&lq=1) I implemented the "Catch-All" solution suggested in that link.

```
app.use("/", express.Router());
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"));
});
```

This solved my refreshing problem, but it broke all of my `fetch` calls. For instance:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "username": user.value,
        "password": pass.value,
    }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Which works fine if I comment out the above `app.use` and `app.get` lines, is giving me an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I think the promise returned by `response.json()` is being rejected, based on some `console.log` debugging I did. However, it seems that `response` is the same regardless of whether I comment out those lines. So I am not sure why it would fail.

Comment: is your response actually an html file? why are you trying to read it as `json` if its html?

Comment: Your server is returning an HTML file (which starts with `<` as its first character (position 0)), but your client code is expecting JSON.  It's attempting to parse the HTML as JSON, hence the error.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line, you are attaching empty router to `/` route.

```
app.use("/", express.Router());
```

So, when your client hits `/api/login`, it couldn't match to any route. Hence, it gets handled by `*` that send `html` file.

Since, `/api/login` is returning `html` file with `200` message, `fetch` tries to json-parse the `html` response. Thus, `fetch` throws an error.

**Solution:**

`app.use("/", // valid router);`