# syntax error only on first load, after refresh page then will be gone

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I got this error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Whenever I clear browsing data and refresh page to load my API, but it only shows in the first load, then will be gone after refresh again.
Looks like it is because of cookies or something; is there anybody can help me out?

JS CODE:

```js
function showDoctorinfo(){
    loading();
    var url = './api/api.php?action=showDoctorinfo';
    fetch(url, 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: { 
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // 'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        },
    ) 
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.status === 204) {
            closeLoading();
            document.getElementById("output-searchDoctorInfo").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("allDoctors").style.display = 'none';
            console.log('no doctor information')
            return;
        }
        if(response.status === 429) {
            closeLoading();
            document.getElementById("output-searchDoctorInfo").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("allDoctors").style.display = 'none';
            console.log('rate limit exceeded')
            return;
        }
        response.json().then(function(data){
            closeLoading();
            document.getElementById("output-searchDoctorInfo").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("allDoctors").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("output-doctorinfo").style.display = 'block';
            console.log(data);
            var source = document.getElementById("doctorinfo-template").innerHTML;
            var myTpl = Handlebars.compile(source);
            Handlebars.registerHelper("compare",function(v1, v2, options){
                if(v1 > v2){
                    return options.fn(this);
                }else{
                    return options.inverse(this);
                }
            })
    
            var compiledData = myTpl(data);
            document.getElementById("output-doctorinfo").innerHTML = compiledData;        
            })
        }) 
        .catch(function () {
            closeLoading();
            document.getElementById("alertMessage").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("alertMessage").innerHTML="Unalbe to connect, please check your internet connection and try again..";
            setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("alertMessage").style.display="none"}, 4000);
        });
}
outStr = showDoctorinfo();
```

API.PHP CODE:

```php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionOBJ'])) {//check session
        $_SESSION['sessionOBJ'] = new doctorSession(); //instantiate session to start using
    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell, since your PHP code is not complete enough; wild guess is that your PHP code or server spits out some HTML error page when session already exists - isn't entire API response creation inside that negative "check session" block? What response body you see exactly in the network console? Does your app install any service worker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last I found I forget to these two lines in the begining of my php file, private $_startTime; private $_requestCounter; (I used them in my php file for ratelimit)