# I can't fetch the json from server

Tags: node.js

**Controller**

```
const User = require('../Models/User')
const errHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const path = require('path')

    const registerUser = errHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const { name, nickName, email, password, role, perk } = req.body;
    
        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            nickName,
            password,
            email,
            role,
            perk
        })
    
        res.status(201)
            .sendFile(path.resolve('./Views/register.html'))
    
    })
```

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <script>

        fetchUserData();

        function fetchUserData() {
            const fetchUser = fetch('http://localhost:5000/auth/register', {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

After I make post requrest, it throws "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError": Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

I tried all of these [React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit) solutions but it didn't work.

Then I tried to include my json in controller like:

```
res.status(201)
        .json({
            success: true,
            data: user
        })
        .sendFile(path.resolve('./Views/register.html'))
```

But this time it couldn't define the JSON.

The picture of my initial problem :

[image: This is my initial problem.]

**Routings**

```
Router.post('/register', registerUser)

Router.use('/auth', auth) // this is index.js router

app.use('/', Router); // server router
```

So my routing is to http://localhost:5000/auth/register

Comment: looks like the response is in html while you try parsing it as json

Comment: What can I do now ?

Comment: Since you are getting a `404` your issue is most likely the routing, can you show the routing code

Comment: I've shown it now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `res.sendFile` and `res.json` together.

- `res.json()` represents the HTTP response.
- `res.sendFile()` transfers the file at the given path.

Comment: How can I use my json which I get from post request in my view render ?

Comment: you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory  y
`app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`
`app.set('view engine', 'pug')`; // some tamplate like handelbars or pug
`res.render("auth", {orders:your_json});`