# VM1835:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (REACT/EXPRESS)

Tags: reactjs, express

I am wondering why I am getting this error:

```
VM1835:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here is my code (frontend)

```
export default function RecipeList() {
  const retrieveAllRecipes = function () {
    fetch(`/`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
      })
  }

  retrieveAllRecipes()
  return <div className="recipe-list"></div>
}
```

Here is my serverside code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  pool
    .query('SELECT * FROM recipes')
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).send(result.rows)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

Database (PostgreSQL retrieval works fine on other db calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit)

Comment: No. I reviewed this answer and given the comment responding to the accepted answer, it seems that the accepted answer is problematic.

Comment: Can you try sending the `Accept` header too? 
*It's a GET request, so sending a Content-Type header is simply wrong. There is no content, in the request, to describe the type of. Setting the Accept header could solve the problem*