# trouble with fetch in a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am having trouble getting a react component to work which is supposed to fetch data form a webserver.
using curl I can do this:

```
curl --data "service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetCapabilities" https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_hl_hp
```

which works.
so then I tried to make a component which would do the same:

```
export const AsyncFetchTest = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string>('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch('https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_hl_hp', {
      method: 'POST',
      // mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:3000',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
     },
      body: 'service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetCapabilities',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])
  console.log('DEBUG data', data)

  return <></>
}
```

if I add this to the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` I get this error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_hl_hp' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

if I don't have it in there, I get this:

> VM33:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "`<HTML>`
> <HE"... is not valid JSON

which is weird, because I am expecting a json, not a html.

What is it I am missing here? Thank you so much for help!

Comment: To request JSON from an endpoint you use the `Accept` header, not the `Content-Type` header. No guarantee this works though, as it depends on the endpoint to implement it.

Comment: I think you need this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283829/11877521

Comment: thanks for you replys, but it does not solve the issue. i just figured, that the cors error disapears, when using another header type: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` then i get a kind of readable html document back - wich sais `mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.` meaning: i do get something back, but not what i am expecting (see curl example in the question.

Comment: Not how that works! If `Accept` didn't work you're basically out of luck and will not be able to do this without the aid of a separate server or changing their api.

Comment: hi, i did find the solution: it had nothing to do with cors (or not in the way i was expecting): this works:  `body: new URLSearchParams({
        'service': 'wfs',
        'version': '1.1.0',
        'request': 'GetCapabilities'
    }),` and this does not: `body: '(service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetCapabilities)',` why? i have no clue...